# Responsive design and hiding div element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to hide a piece of div element on a desktop version of a website and display it on a mobile. However using media query does not allow me . Do you know what might cause the problem? Below is my code:

```
   @media all and(min-device-width: 768px){

.Products{display:block;}
.Products-Mobile{display:none;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}

@media all and(min-device-width: 321px) and (max-device-width: 767px){

.Products{display:block;}
.Products-Mobile{display:none;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}
@media all and(max-device-width: 320px){

.Products{display:none;}
.Products-Mobile{display:block;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}
```

And my html:

```
    <!-- This class will be displayed on the desktop version of the site and will be hidden on the mobile -->
<div class="Products">
 Desktop test   
</div>


<!-- This class will be displayed on the desktop version of the site and will be hidden on the mobile -->
<div class="Products-Mobile">this is mobile test</div>


<!-- This class will be displayed on the mobile and the desktop version of the site -->
<div cass="Benefits">
content
</div>
```

Comment: Do you specify main css above or below media queries? Check console if your media queries take effect and/or is overrided

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very simple... Just add a space between `and` and `(min...)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your media queries to the following:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px){

.Products{display:block;}
.Products-Mobile{display:none;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}

@media all and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 767px){

.Products{display:block;}
.Products-Mobile{display:none;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px){

.Products{display:none;}
.Products-Mobile{display:block;}
.Benefits{ display:block;}
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nos7yuk7/). Removed `-device-` from your media queries.

**EDIT**

To answer questions regarding the use of `-device-` in media queries - [this has been deprecated in Media Queries Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#changes-2012). From W3C:

> To query for the size of the viewport (or the page box on page media),
>   the width, height and aspect-ratio media features should be used,
>   rather than device-width, device-height and device-aspect-ratio, which
>   refer to the physical size of the the device regardless of how much
>   space is available for the document being laid out. The device-* media
>   features are also sometimes used as a proxy to detect mobile devices.
>   Instead, authors should use media features that better represent the
>   aspect of the device that they are attempting to style against.

Comment: `-device-` is valid. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Comment: @Justinas actually `-device-` has been deprecated in Media Queries Level 4. [Source](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#mf-deprecated). I'll add clarification in my answer.